# Impossible result in c linked list

Tags: c, macos, linked-list, stack-overflow

I've been trying to create a simple c linked list, but I've got really funny result

here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef char * String;

typedef struct node{
    String value;
    struct node * next;
    struct node * prev;
}Node;

struct node * createLinkList(){
    struct node * root=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    root->value="head";
    root->prev=NULL;
    root->next=NULL;
    return root;
}

Node * insert(String val,Node * root){
    Node * tempNode=root;
    Node * newNode=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    printf("head value : %s\n",tempNode->value );
    while(tempNode->next !=  NULL){
        tempNode=tempNode->next;
        printf("latest node value : %s\n", tempNode->value);
    }
    newNode->prev=tempNode;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    newNode->value=val;
    printf("newly added node value : %s\n", newNode->value);
    tempNode->next=newNode;
    return root;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node * dblList=createLinkList();
    String val=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        printf("please enter value(node #%i): ",i);
        scanf("%s",val);
        dblList=insert(val,dblList);
    }
}
```

and here is the result that I've got:

```
please enter value(node #0): one
head value : head
newly added node value : one
please enter value(node #1): two
head value : head
latest node value : two
newly added node value : two
```

anyone can explain what's going on here????
I mean when I've entered the second value
latest node value must be the fist value that I've entered but it's the newly entered one!

is it a stack overflow or am I doing something wrong!?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). You could also debug-print pointers using `%p` format control ...

Comment: I've compiled it `using gcc -o 4 4.c -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **allocate a new string *inside* the loop**, not before it:

```
#define LEN 100
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    char* val=malloc(LEN);
    memset (val, 0, LEN);
    printf("please enter value(node #%i): ",i);
    fflush(NULL);
    fgets(val, LEN, stdin);
    dblList=insert(val,dblList);
}
```

Actually you should better use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)    {
    char* line=NULL;
    size_t linsiz=0;
    printf("please enter value(node #%i): ",i);
    fflush(NULL);
    ssize_t linlen = getline(&line,&linsiz,stdin);
    dblList=insert(line,dblList);
}
```

**Don't forget to later `free` the memory zones allocated inside the heap!** Read [memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) & [C dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) & [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) wikipages. Consider also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)...

Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and use a debugger (`gdb`). Or at least, debug-print the address of the memory zone, e.g. put in several places a line like

```
    printf("at %s:%d val=%p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, (void*)val);
```

Comment: @Random_Default_User: What's weird about that? Your linked list contains the pointer `val`. You originally populate `val` with `"one"`, then you populate it with `"two"`; but both times, it's pointing to the same memory location, and your linked-list still contains it.

Comment: you're right here is the result when I've moved the `String val=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);` inside of for loop: `please enter value(node #0): one
head value : head
newly added node value : one
please enter value(node #1): two
head value : head
latest node value : one
newly added node value : two`

Comment: can anyone explain why moving that allocation inside of loop solved the problem?